# need layout to be rendered before a partial view (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First off, this is happening in ASP.net MVC4 using razor

I currently have a layout that I use on all the pages in the solution.

the layout includes `@RenderBody()` that loads a the content.

my index.cshtml includes a partial view and this partial view needs some data that will only exist after the code in the layout has been executed.

I placed breakpoints at the start of the partial view and at the start of the layout and the partial is being rendered first, any way to modify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, as I imagine it could cause more subtle problems in the framework than it would solve.

Without more details, it *really* sounds like the true issue here is the fact that this data will only exist after the layout has rendered.  The views (layout included) should really just be binding to data that's already been processed.  There shouldn't be additional logic in the view, nothing beyond just rendering what they've been given into a UI.

By the time you get to `return View()` in the controller, all business logic processing should be done and you should just be building the UI from the completed model.  In short, this logic that's in the layout *probably* belongs on a model.

Comment: ... or in the controller. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster: Less probable, but I suppose possible.  Remember though, keep the controllers light and the models heavy.

Comment: There's more than enough written on that subject and I for one don't like _view_ models to contain too much logic.

Comment: @David that makes a lot of sense, in my case, working with some session data in the layout view. why? because my layout doesn't have a controller where I can include what I need and because I cant seem to access the session from my model. any suggestions?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC, your HTTP-related variables are present as Controller properties. You can for example create a base controller from which all your controllers inherit, that in its constructor puts the `this.Session["Username"]` data in the `ViewBag.Username`, for example, then you can refer to that viewbag property on any page rendered through your base controller. Another way would be to create a base `ViewModel` that all your _models_ inherit from, with a `LoggedInUsername` property, which you then again fill from the base controller, but it's more work passing that base model around.

Comment: @mmilan: Without knowing more about the problem being addressed, my suggestions are mostly high-level at best.  Not relying on session is probably my most pertinent suggestion, though it's of little consolation without knowing more about the big picture.  One idea could be to abstract Session behind an object of its own and access it from the controller via that object.  The point of the abstraction would be to de-couple the controller logic from the session dependency.  Then you can perform that logic (perhaps even on that object instead of in the controller) and output to view data.